# Inline type-casting in objective-c with dot notation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This question is pure curiosity.

In Xcode, why does this work:

```
if (view.class == [UITextView class]) {
    UITextView *tview = (UITextView *)view;
    tview.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.020 green:0.549 blue:0.961 alpha:1.];
}
```

But the following results in the error message `Property 'textColor' not found on object of type 'UIView *'`:

```
if (view.class == [UITextView class]) {
    (UITextView *)view.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.020 green:0.549 blue:0.961 alpha:1.];
}
```

Intuitively, these should accomplish the exact same thing.

But then if I enclose the inline cast in parentheses, it works fine:

```
if (view.class == [UITextView class]) {
    ((UITextView *)view).textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.020 green:0.549 blue:0.961 alpha:1.];
}
```

I suspect it just has to do with how C handles order of operations, but I would be curious to hear an explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (view.class == [UITextView class]) {
    (UITextView *)view.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.020 green:0.549 blue:0.961 alpha:1.];
}
```

Due to order of precedence, the `(UITextView*)` will act as a cast on the result of `view.textColor`, meaning `.textColor` will be accessed within the `UIView*` first before it's cast to a `UITextView*`

```
if (view.class == [UITextView class]) {
    ((UITextView *)view).textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.020 green:0.549 blue:0.961 alpha:1.];
}
```

In this, the extra parentheses will inform the compiler that sub-expression needs to be computed first, before the rest of the expression. As such, this is casting `view` to be a `UITextView*`. The side effect of that expression is a `UITextView*` instance, meaning that the `.textColor` property can be found on the instance it's being used against.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same approach with my models, wrapped up into a **typecasting helper function** per entity.

```
// Cast an `entity` to a `user`.
TPUser *user(TPEntity *entity)
{ return ([entity isKindOfClass:[TPUser class]]) ? (TPUser*)entity : nil; }
```

So it is safe to use like this...

```
someUI.text = user(entity).name;
```

...as it returns `nil` when casting fails.

---

For this case it goes like:

```
UITextField *textField(UIView *view)
{ return ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) ? (UITextField*)view : nil; }
```